How to prevent saving of images on pages
On one of my sharepoint pages I display an image. In site assests I have set this image to download only. However when testing it seems that visitors are still able to right click on the image on the page and save it to their device.
Is there any way to prevent this?
As a sidenote I dont want to completely block downloads as their are some shared documents that I want to allow people to download. This is on university sharepoint, with my own site created, so I am not an overall admin, but I am owner of the site.

I think that is a browser level option and not SharePoint specific. So, you will not have any option/setting in SharePoint to prevent from using "save as" browser level option.
